# What Magento Event Fires when adding to cart a 'last ordered item'

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

What event fires when the user is on My Account page and clicks 'Add to Cart' in the 'My Orders: Last Ordered Items' area? Hopefully I am making sense, below is an image from the My Account page and the button I am talking about:

[image]

I am attempting to create an observer that will react to this event and remove/change deprecated products from the users order (products we no longer want to sell).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it should be **checkout_cart_product_add_after**
You can check magento 1.9 events cheat sheet for more about events.

https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/